# How do I get notified when a command is finished and Powershell is back to prompt?

Tags: powershell

I'm doing some testing job, and a part of it is to regularly write files to some hardware. The thing is, the write can take as short as 20 seconds, or as long as several minutes. Staring at the screen and waiting for it to be done is a huge waste of time, so I'm wondering if there is a way to get notified (like making a beep sound by using [console]::beep() ) when the command is done and the Powershell is back to prompt?

Comment: PowerShell Alert for 1-Minute >  [console]::beep(500,60000)

Comment: Powershell "Asterisk" Alert for Windows > [System.Media.SystemSounds]::Asterisk.Play()

Comment: Write-Host "`a"  ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can edit your `prompt` function:

```
$function:prompt = @"
{0}
[console]::beep()
"@ -f $function:prompt.ToString()
```

---

A more concise version (compliments of [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)) if you don't mind semi-colon delimited commands:

```
$function:prompt = "$function:prompt; [console]::beep()"
```

Answer (score 1):

**PowerShell Alert when command is finished** :

```
"Answer" | out-file response.txt
[console]::beep(500,300)
```

Powershell > **[console]::beep** for 1-Minute :

```
[console]::beep(500,60000)
```

Also - Try using the "Asterisk" Alert :

```
[System.Media.SystemSounds]::Asterisk.Play()
```